# Special Characters with Swift(Fixed check bottom of the main post)

Tags: php, json

Hi everyone i have a swift project about user registration, but i have problems with special characters like "ö,ü,ğ" when user entered thats they prints in xcode ok , but when sending json string that's converting like this ömer > &oumlmer

how can i fix this ? how can i change encoding for this special characters.

Code :

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: (URL(string: "xxxx.com/userregister.php") )! );
request.httpMethod = "POST";
let userstring = "My name is ömer";  
print(userstring)  //Everything okey printing : My name is Ömer
requst.httpBody=userstring.data(using: .utf8)    //I think problem is here.Its saving to database like : My name is &oumlMer
```

UserRegister.php

```
<?php 
require("Conn.php");
require("MySQLDao.php");

$email = htmlentities($_POST["email"]);
$password = htmlentities($_POST["password"]);
$name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
$gsm = htmlentities($_POST["gsm"]);
$onayid = "0";
$surname = htmlentities($_POST["surname"]);
$qrcodeid = htmlentities($_POST["qrcodeid"]);
$returnValue = array();

if(empty($email) || empty($password))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "Missing required fieldd";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao = new MySQLDao();
$dao->openConnection();
$userDetails = $dao->getUserDetails($email);

if(!empty($userDetails))
{
$returnValue["status"] = "error";
$returnValue["message"] = "User already exists";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$secure_password = md5($password); // I do this, so that user password cannot be read even by me

$result = $dao->registerUser($email,$secure_password,$name,$gsm,$onayid,$surname,$qrcodeid);

if($result)
{
$returnValue["status"] = "Success";
$returnValue["message"] = "User is registered";
echo json_encode($returnValue);
return;
}

$dao->closeConnection();

?>
```

Connection codes :

```
public function openConnection() {
$this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, $this->dbname);
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $this->conn);
    mb_language('uni'); 
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $this->conn);
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$this->conn);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
echo new Exception("Could not establish connection with database");
}
```

FIXED  (must be change .php file mysql connection ) :

```
if (!$this->conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $this->conn->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $this->conn->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: I think your problem is in userregister.php file. So share code from it.

Comment: Okey , i added that

Comment: I am not an PHP expert, but my guess would be that htmlentities() is the culprit. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php: "Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is htmlentities() function.
It converts all applicable characters to HTML entities.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

It does not prevent SQL injection. So you don't need it.
You can look this.
[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Try this.

```
if (!$this->conn->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $this->conn->error);
    exit();
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $this->conn->character_set_name());
}
```

Comment: I deleted htmlentities function but now im giving in database this : My name is Ã¶mer

Comment: So your database character collection is not utf8 or database connection does not use utf8

Comment: My database character collection is utf8_general_ci

Comment: If you are sure that so you need something like that http://php.net/manual/tr/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: I added my connection php codes in first post can you check it ?